# Kernel module for net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, modprobe, sysctl, kernel-parameters

This is on the Linux OS.

I see that on some machines the `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` variable doesn't exist until I `modprobe` the `br_netfilter` filter. I also see that there are some machines where the `bridge` module is loaded and that itself brings in this variable.

Is there a way to know which module I should load in order to get a particular variable ?

Comment: Why the -1 ? Any ways to improve question quality ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no automatic database relating sysctl variables to modules. You can search the module binary and hope that the variable name isn't found in other strings (this one isn't). Search for the last part, i.e. `bridge-nf-call-iptables` — the full string isn't present in the binary, it's constructed dynamically.

```
grep -rl bridge-nf-call-iptables /lib/modules/`uname -r`
```

Alternatively, you can check the documentation — but it doesn't always tell you, and in this case [it doesn't say](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt). So you're left with the [source code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/). First look for the string (again, only the last part); in recent kernels it's in [`net/bridge/br_netfilter_hooks.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/bridge/br_netfilter_hooks.c?v=4.9). Now check the [makefile in the same directory](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/bridge/Makefile?v=4.9) to see how this source file is built. The relevant line is

```
br_netfilter-y := br_netfilter_hooks.o
```

which means that if the `br_netfilter` module is built then it contains the code from `br_netfilter_hooks.c`, thus the `br_netfilter` module is the one you need.